# How to set up contractNetworks in gnosis safe to use protocol kit on localhost

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to use protocol kit and safeSdk to test gnosis safe. I also want to modify existing contracts to add additional features to the safe contracts and modules. To do these things, I was trying to set up safe on my localhost using ganache. But I don't know which contracts to deploy to set the fields in contract Networks and what each of these contracts do.

How can I find the code of these contracts, and learn better how to use them.

```
const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
  [chainId]: {
    safeMasterCopyAddress: '<MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS>',
    safeProxyFactoryAddress: '<PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS>',
    multiSendAddress: '<MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS>',
    multiSendCallOnlyAddress: '<MULTI_SEND_CALL_ONLY_ADDRESS>',
    fallbackHandlerAddress: '<FALLBACK_HANDLER_ADDRESS>',
    signMessageLibAddress: '<SIGN_MESSAGE_LIB_ADDRESS>',
    createCallAddress: '<CREATE_CALL_ADDRESS>',
    safeMasterCopyAbi: '<MASTER_COPY_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    safeProxyFactoryAbi: '<PROXY_FACTORY_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    multiSendAbi: '<MULTI_SEND_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    multiSendCallOnlyAbi: '<MULTI_SEND_CALL_ONLY_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    fallbackHandlerAbi: '<FALLBACK_HANDLER_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    signMessageLibAbi: '<SIGN_MESSAGE_LIB_ABI>', // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
    createCallAbi: '<CREATE_CALL_ABI>' // Optional. Only needed with web3.js
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure it out? i need to know too